# VBA: looping through a list of named ranges and pasting them to another sheet based on an address reference

Tags: loops, excel, range, named, vba

I am making some VBA code to help me do the following:

Paste a list of all named ranges
Loop through the list and copy/select ranges based on the list
Each selection will be pasted on another sheet given an address reference with a certain offset from that address

I am pretty new to VBA so I have put together some code that I think will do the trick but I am getting run time errors. Could someone help me troubleshoot or provide suggestions?

My code is here:

```
Sub RangeLoop()

Sheets("RANGEMATCH").Select
Range("A1").ListNames

Dim columnrange As Range
Dim m As Long
Dim address As Range

Set columnrange = Sheets("RANGEMATCH").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlConstants)

With columnrange
    For m = 1 To columnrange.Areas.Count
        Set address = Sheets("RANGEMATCH").Range(.Areas(m).Cells(1, 7).Value)
        Range(m).Copy Sheets("ETIE").Range(address.Offset(1, 10))
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Here is an example workbook of what I am working with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AodOP_8DnJnFdHJoQ0xBM3JUUGJxT3EyRXN0T2ltUmc&usp=sharing

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: You may benefit from these two tips: use `Option Explicit` — [see TLiebe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/whats-an-option-strict-and-explicit) and [avoid using `Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) — including avoiding using `Activate`

Comment: Also, you may want to tell us what the error is, and which line is it on as well.

Comment: The error shows up on this line:   

    Range(m).Copy Sheets("ETIE").Range(address.Offset(1, 10))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Range() function expects a string variable.  Either the name of a range or a cell reference like "A1"

```
Range(m).Copy Sheets("ETIE").Range(address.Offset(1, 10))
```

m is a number so that won't work.  You'll need to reference the thing that you want to copy.  I think that might just be your `address` object that you set in the line before:

```
address.Copy Sheets("ETIE").Range(address.Offset(1, 10))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The suggestion is good but it doesnt help me here. 

The address variable is the destination where I want to paste my range ...the address is set to a column with multiple cell coordinates in them. 

Range(m) is how I am trying to identify/pull in the named range I created.  

I basically have a 2 lists, one with named ranges and a few cells to the right is a list of destination addresses where those ranges should be pasted. I want this loop to walk down list one (with ranges) and pull them in, at the same time walk down the second list (of addresses) and use them

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions on how I can pull in the required information into the code? All I need is how to reference a cell value as a name for a named range and then use another cell value as an address on another sheet where to paste that range. Would be a huge help. Thank you!

Comment: Are the ranges more than one cell in size?  If not, you can use `Sheets("Destination").Range(Sheets("Original").Range("theAddress")) = Sheets("Original").Range("theValue")`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The ranges are much larger than one cell..I posted an example spreadsheet in the link at the top of the post so you can take a look at what I am dealing with.